# I'm not able to understand the dynamic data tables scenarios in Karate

Tags: karate

Anybody know how to use the csv file to create a dynamic data tables.

I'm trying to use the Code defined in the documentation but it's not working for me.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is not very detailed. Please add more information like the code you've tried to use. You can find a good Guideline on _How do I ask a good question?_ [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: which version for karate are you using? try 0.9.2 it should work.

Answer (score 1):

The `read` function accepts `csv` files and creates an array of json objects from the csv. Header row is always expected and the header is used to create the name of the object members.

Suppose you have a csv like this:

[data.csv]:

```
name,likes
Cucuma,1
Canyon,2
Stevens,3
```

Then the following test is green

```
  Scenario: Read CSV file and convert that to json
    Given json dataFromCsv = read('data.csv')
    Then match dataFromCsv ==
    """
    [
      {name : "Cucuma", likes : '1'}
      {name : "Canyon", likes : '2'}
      {name : "Stevens", likes : '3'}
    ]
    """
```

[You can find that example here](https://github.com/peterquiel/karate-experiment/blob/master/src/test/groovy/com/github/peterquiel/karate/experiment/karate-syntax-collection.feature#L94). It's a gradle and groovy based test, but I hope it helps.

Comment: one more thing, here i'm trying to read csv file directly but not able to read as given in documentation.  Here is my code.  Scenario Outline: get all users and then get the first user by id

Given path 'users'
* print '<id>' 
And request read('request.json')
When method post
Then status 201
Examples:
| read('ss.csv') |  ss.csv : id 11 12

Comment: If this is a different question, create one? Did you checkout my example? Did it work? 
Your code example isn't complete, that makes it difficult to understand your problem.